# O que representa "== $0" ao inspecionar uma página?

Tags: javascript, html

Ao inspecionar uma página, percebi que aparece `== $0` que não faz parte do HTML.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que significa este código? Faz parte do JavaScript?

Comment: Saudações, Lorena. Tomei a liberdade para editar sua pergunta de forma a deixar mais claro quanto a dúvida sobre `== $0`. Quanto a sua outra dúvida, de manter o cabeçalho fixo, recomendo que abra uma pergunta nova, pois não tem relação com esta dúvida.

Comment: Ser muito obrigada. Desculpe.

Answer (score 5):

É o elemento que está selecionado. Ele pode ser referenciado no console do JavaScript com a variável `$0`. Por exemplo (usando jQuery), se você digitar isso no console:

```
$($0).html()
```

Vai aparecer o HTML do elemento que você selecionou (pode testar aqui na página do Stack Overflow mesmo). É claro que isso não se limita a chamar `html()`, você pode fazer as manipulações que quiser no DOM usando o `$0`.

Answer (score 5):

`$0` é uma variável javascript que as ferramentas de desenvolvedor (dev tools) cria pra facilitar a nossa vida, quando usado no terminal ela referência o elemento selecionado na aba `elements`, por isso o `== $0`, porque o elemento selecionado é igual a `$0`

Logo, em um HTML:

```
<p id="exemplo">Exemplo</p>
```

Chamar `$0` (tendo esse elemento selecionado no dev tools) é equivalente a:

```
document.getElementById('exemplo');
```

ou

```
document.querySelector('#exemplo');
```

Entre outros

Apenas para fins de curiosidade, é possível referenciar comentários com o `$0`, basta seleciona-lo, porém, em vez de retornar uma instância de `HTMLElement`, retorna uma instância de `Comment`